# Regex to Match D or E followed by 2-3 digits

Tags: regex

I've been looking for a regex to match a string that either starts with a D or an E followed 2 or 3 digits. I'm pretty terrible at writing regex but this is what I tried: ^[DE]{1}[0-9]{1,2}$

Thank you

Comment: you had used the "start of line" and "end of line" symbol.
so, you just get result when whole line match.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> `starts with D or an E followed by 2 or 3 digits`

You're close. Try this regex:

```
^[DE][0-9]{2,3}$
```

You don't need `{1}` as that is by default true and digits should be `{2,3}` instead of `{1,2}`

Comment: [DE][0-9]{2,3}$ works perfectly!!! The preceding caret was silly of me and its matching everything i wanted it too now. Thank you!